# Discrete Math - Write the following sequences as explicit formulas

Tags: discrete-mathematics

6. Write the following sequences as explicit formulas ak whose first term uses k=1
7. -1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4, 4, ....
8. 0,3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, .....

I had two others, i figured those out pretty easily, I just cant seem to figure out these two.

Anyone know where to begin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$7.$
$$a_k = (-1)^k\left[\frac{k+1}{2}\right]$$
$8.$
$$a_k = a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}$$

Comment: For k = 2 (-1)^2 = 1 (3/2) = 3/2 right? So the first wouldn't work or am i just way too tired to be looking at it?

Comment: $[x]$ means Gaussian function that returns the biggest integer that is not less than x (in other words, 'floor function'). So $\left[\frac32\right]=1$.

Comment: OHH floor. I got it now. Thank you

Comment: For 8) is that (ak-1) + (ak-2) or is it formatted differently?

Comment: That is a_{k-1} + a_{k-2}. Sum of two previous terms.

Comment: hm, How does that work with 0,3 though? I might of not had the 0 there when i asked the question, i edited it a few minutes ago. My bad

Comment: 3 was the first term. I see you added 0. Is the 1st one really 0, not 1?

Comment: Yes it is 0, that is what is throwing me off, because if it was 1 your solution makes alot of sense and is quite intelligent.

Comment: I believe the 0 should be treated as an exception. So the above equation holds for $k\geq4$. If you really need to include 0 and provide a formula that works for all those shown numbers from 0 through 47, there can be infinite number of ugly formula including 7th order polynomial, etc. But the next number wouldn't be 76. So it's matter of your choice what you think would be the next number - 76 or not. If you still believe it will be 76 then the above equation is the answer as it is too obvious. If it's not the correct answer then I bet you can complain to the person who wrote the question.

Comment: I'm going to go with your solution, It seems logical to me. Thanks dude. Much appreciated for taking your time to help.

Comment: oh my god. The 0 wasnt there. I have an unedited version. Sorry dude, thanks again

Comment: No problem. My pleasure!